# drupal 7 chrome not loading css rules

Tags: css, google-chrome, drupal-7

After editing the css file that holds all of the custom css the site stopped displaying correctly in chrome. IE looks fine... could it be something in my devtools that changed the way it loads in chrome?

Or is there an error in the file itself:

```
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/themes/stark/layout.css?mdyj3p");
```

Head-:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="ltr">

<head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/themes/stark/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Florabelle Martha&#039;s Vineyard RSS" href="http://florabellemv.com/rss.xml" />
  <title>Florabelle Martha&#039;s Vineyard | perfume, bath &amp; body, and more...</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://florabellemv.com/modules/system/system.base.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/modules/system/system.menus.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/modules/system/system.messages.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/modules/system/system.theme.css?mdyj3p");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://florabellemv.com/modules/field/theme/field.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/modules/node/node.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/uc_order.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_product/uc_product.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_store/uc_store.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/modules/user/user.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?mdyj3p");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/colorbox/styles/default/colorbox_default_style.css?mdyj3p");
@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?mdyj3p");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/themes/stark/layout.css?mdyj3p");</style>
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://florabellemv.com/sites/default/files/fontyourface/fontsquirrel/CAC-Champagne-fontfacekit/stylesheet.css?mdyj3p");</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bilbo:regular|Dancing+Script:regular|Dawning+of+a+New+Day:regular|Great+Vibes:regular|Italianno:regular|Josefin+Slab:300italic|Lovers+Quarrel:regular|Niconne:regular|Parisienne:regular|Petit+Formal+Script:regular|Poiret+One:regular|Qwigley:regular|Spirax:regular|Tangerine:700|Zeyada:regular&amp;subset=latin-ext,latin,cyrillic" media="all" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://florabellemv.com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://florabellemv.com/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://florabellemv.com/misc/drupal.js?mdyj3p"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js?mdyj3p"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/colorbox/js/colorbox.js?mdyj3p"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://florabellemv.com/sites/all/modules/colorbox/styles/default/colorbox_default_style.js?mdyj3p"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.edgefonts.net/alex-brush:n4;allura:n4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\u002F", "pathPrefix":"", "ajaxPageState":{"theme":"stark", "theme_token":"9zudAyr6gjtq_GMpTSgK8zXymLTi3LsBuS9rwwU9fXw", "css":{"modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.base.css":1, "modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.menus.css":1, "modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.messages.css":1, "modules\u002Fsystem\u002Fsystem.theme.css":1, "modules\u002Ffield\u002Ftheme\u002Ffield.css":1, "modules\u002Fnode\u002Fnode.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fubercart\u002Fuc_attribute\u002Fuc_attribute.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fubercart\u002Fuc_order\u002Fuc_order.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fubercart\u002Fuc_product\u002Fuc_product.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fubercart\u002Fuc_store\u002Fuc_store.css":1, "modules\u002Fuser\u002Fuser.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fviews\u002Fcss\u002Fviews.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fcolorbox\u002Fstyles\u002Fdefault\u002Fcolorbox_default_style.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fctools\u002Fcss\u002Fctools.css":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fthemes\u002Fstark\u002Flayout.css":1, "sites\u002Fdefault\u002Ffiles\u002Ffontyourface\u002Ffontsquirrel\u002FCAC-Champagne-fontfacekit\u002Fstylesheet.css":1, "http:\u002F\u002Ffonts.googleapis.com\u002Fcss?family=Bilbo:regular|Dancing+Script:regular|Dawning+of+a+New+Day:regular|Great+Vibes:regular|Italianno:regular|Josefin+Slab:300italic|Lovers+Quarrel:regular|Niconne:regular|Parisienne:regular|Petit+Formal+Script:regular|Poiret+One:regular|Qwigley:regular|Spirax:regular|Tangerine:700|Zeyada:regular\u0026subset=latin-ext,latin,cyrillic":1}, "js":{"misc\u002Fjquery.js":1, "misc\u002Fjquery.once.js":1, "misc\u002Fdrupal.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Flibraries\u002Fcolorbox\u002Fcolorbox\u002Fjquery.colorbox-min.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fcolorbox\u002Fjs\u002Fcolorbox.js":1, "sites\u002Fall\u002Fmodules\u002Fcolorbox\u002Fstyles\u002Fdefault\u002Fcolorbox_default_style.js":1, "\u002F\u002Fuse.edgefonts.net\u002Falex-brush:n4;allura:n4.js":1}}, "colorbox":{"transition":"elastic", "speed":"350", "opacity":"0.85", "slideshow":false, "slideshowAuto":true, "slideshowSpeed":"2500", "slideshowStart":"start slideshow", "slideshowStop":"stop slideshow", "current":"{current} of {total}", "previous":"« Prev", "next":"Next »", "close":"Close", "overlayClose":true, "maxWidth":"100%", "maxHeight":"100%", "initialWidth":"300", "initialHeight":"100", "fixed":true, "scrolling":true}});
//--><!]]>
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/stark/selectbox/jquery.selectBox.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/stark/selectbox/jquery.selectBox.css"/>


</head>
```

here is what it looks like in ie now:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2eT0kwnwUQ4VXlsQ0M5TUlvRFE

[My Website](http://www.florabellemv.com)

Comment: Your question does not have the information I or someone else needs to get a handle on what is happening. Think about expanding it and making it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I hope that is clearer. If you need more info I am happy to explain more. Thanks again!!

Comment: You can try with Incognito mode in Chrome so your plugins won't affect your experience. And it wouldn't be bad if you attach a screenshot of the desired aspect you wish (as you see it in IE), so we can compare.

Comment: Thanks desert.... the image link is there. mo luck w incognito mode....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS has errors in it. You're defining some attributes but not giving them a value, such as `color:;`. Also, `position` is misspelled as `positon`. See [validator results](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://www.florabellemv.com/sites/all/themes/stark/layout.css?mdyj3p&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) for details.

I'm guessing IE isn't as picky with invalid CSS as Chrome is. Try fixing the errors and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: It was a parse error missing a ")" threw off the whole style sheet in chrome. Thank you Kaivosukeltaja !!